# PHP замена текста между символами

Tags: php

Есть к примеру такая строка:

```
[quote][center][url=текст]текст[/url]
[url=текст]текст[/url][/center][/quote]
```

Подскажите, как при помощи `php` заменить текст между

```
[quote][center][/center][/quote]
```

на свой. К примеру, чтобы было вот так:

```
[quote][center]текст[/center][/quote]
```

Comment: Вы пустые бб-коды отлавливаете или что-то другое пытаетесь сделать?

Comment: Нужно просто заменить содержимое между символами на другое

Comment: Можно решить через preg_replace, но не могу понять, как именно это сделать.

Answer (score 4):

Используйте регулярные выражения:

```
$txt = "[quote][center][url=текст]текст[/url]
        [url=текст]текст[/url][/center][/quote]";


$replace = "новый текст";

$txt = preg_replace("#\[quote\]\[center\][\s\S]+\[/center\]\[/quote\]#im", 
                    "[quote][center]{$replace}[/center][/quote]",
                    $txt);
print_r($txt);
```

Comment: зачем вы экранируете прямые слэши? Они не являются метасимволами или ограничителями шаблона.

Comment: @Эдуард честно сказать хз отчего так вышло :) замечу, что это сделано в строке замены, а не в шаблоне :)

Comment: @Эдуард отредактировал

Comment: да, благодарю ) Сейчас ещё свой вариант добавлю.

Comment: Спасибо за код)

Answer (score 2):

Вариант с подмасками

```
$string = "[quote][center][url=текст]текст[/url][url=текст]текст[/url][/center][/quote]";
$text = 'новый текст';

$pattern = '~(\[quote]\[center])[\s\S]+(\[/center]\[/quote])~';
$replace = '$1'. $text .'$2';

echo preg_replace($pattern, $replace, $string);
```

Comment: Спасибо за код)

Comment: @user242683 если вам более подходит именно мой вариант, отметьте его галочкой.